# combine RewriteRule htaccess 301 Redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the below htaccess rewrite rules to redirect old url files to the new ones.

The first RewriteRule redirects to new url file if the file path requested is `fares/` or `airfares/` or `anyword-fares/` etc.

The second RewriteRule redirects to new URL file only if the url path requested is `flights/`.

My 1st question is, did I write them correctly or leave anything out?

2nd question is, can I combine the two RewriteRules into one or use a rewrite condition to combine them into one?

I'm asking because I will be adding more that will redirect to the new url file of `airfares-flights/`

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*fares/(.*)$ /airfares-flights/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^flights/(.*)$ /airfares-flights/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes your rules are correct.
2. Yes both rules can be combined into one.

Use this .htaccess:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:.*fares|flights)/(.*)$ /airfares-flights/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: it works but I had to remove the `?` before the `*`. It looks like this now `RewriteRule ^(?:.*fares|flights)/(.*)$ /airfares-flights/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: thank you. And if not using the wild card, it will simply look like this? `RewriteRule ^(?:jobs|careers)/(.*)$ /airline-jobs-careers/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`